# Why is there "No matching ctor" for seemingly unambiguous type-hinted constructor call?

Tags: java, clojure, interop, type-hinting

Using Netty from Clojure, the following theoretically unambiguous constructor call fails to resolve, both in Cursive (which incorrectly lists both 3-arity options for disambiguation) and in the REPL (which throws `IllegalArgumentException` *No matching ctor*). The un-hinted version also fails in the same way.

```clj
(DefaultFullHttpResponse. protocol status ^ByteBuf buffer)
```

Available constructor signatures are:

- HttpVersion HttpResponseStatus
- HttpVersion HttpResponseStatus ByteBuf *← unambiguously identified by arity + single type hint*
- HttpVersion HttpResponseStatus boolean
- HttpVersion HttpResponseStatus boolean boolean
- HttpVersion HttpResponseStatus ByteBuf boolean
- HttpVersion HttpResponseStatus ByteBuf boolean boolean
- HttpVersion HttpResponseStatus ByteBuf HttpHeaders HttpHeaders

Why?

Comment: Would you post a complete, minimal project (a grand total of maybe a dozen lines), with which to reproduce the problem? You have shared a somewhat brute-force solution, but an answer to the original question would be enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by "redundantly" hinting the first argument as well:

```clj
(DefaultFullHttpResponse. ^HttpVersion protocol status ^ByteBuf buffer)
```

This was surprising!